# Missing headers folder in custom cocoa framework

Tags: cocoa, frameworks

I'm trying to build a custom framework but for some reason, there is never a headers folder inside after it gets built.

I'm starting off with the Cocoa Framework xcode project and then I add my classes to it. When I build, everything works fine but there is no headers folder and no header files in the framework.

I must be missing something really simple. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I was missing the "Role" column in the frameworks list of files.

Comment: Randall: You should post an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed the "Role" column in the frameworks list of files. It needs to be set to public for them to show up.